# "Find" block alternative that is HDL code compatible

Tags: simulink, hdl

I need to find the index of the minimum value in a vector using all HDL code compatible blocks in simulink. This can be done quite simply using the "Find" block, but sadly this block is not HDL code compatible. Can someone propose an alternative using blocks that are HDL compatible?

[code working with "Find" block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvsCH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [minimum](https://de.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/minimum.html) block, which directly returns the index. This block require the DSP Toolbox.